# How to filter queryset with exclude and ForeignKey

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have two models

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    properties = here

class ReadedEntries(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I get the no readed entries from a user?

I try:

```
not_looked_videos = Entry.objects.exclude(ReadedEntries.objects.filter(user=request.user))
```

but I get:

```
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use isnull to get all enries with empty ReadedEtries set:

```
Entry.objects.filter(readedentries__isnull=True)
```

Or to exclude only readed entries for current:
user

```
Entry.objects.exclude(readedentries__user=request.user))
```

Comment: I try with `readedentries__isnull=False` and works. The readedentries__user=request.user wirks too with the user

Answer (score 1):

1, Filter ~Q(id__in = ids)

where ids = ReadedEntries.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)

2.I am still in process to complete it...

Answer (score 0):

`Entry.objects.exclude(readedentries__isnull=False)`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**